# Calling a macro from another workbook causes macros get skipped

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to perform the below operation from a workbook (Say `A.xlsm`):

1. Opening another workbook (say `B.xlsb`)
2. Calling a macro in `B.xlsb` from `A.xlsm`
3. Save the workbook `B.xlsb`
4. Close the workbook `B.xlsb`

Below is the code in `A.xlsm`:

```
Workbooks.Open(Filename:=B.xlsb).RunAutoMacros Which:=xlAutoOpen
Workbooks(B.xlsb).Activate
Windows(B.xlsb).Activate
Application.Run (B.xlsb& "!MyMacro")
```

Above all works fine, but a macro (`Initialize`, which is for initializing the ribbon object) gets skipped in `B.xlsm` which is should get called at the time of loading of the workbook `B.xlsb`. When I open it manually and then Save and close.

I see the macros `Workbook_Open`, `Workbook_Activate` and `Initialize` (this is configured in an XML to be called at the loading time) gets called in sequence.
But the same when I do from VBA then `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_Activate` are called but `Initialize` gets skipped.

[image: Image showing Initialize macro in B.xlsb]

Comment: Which function in your `B.xlsb` is calling the `Initialise` sub? also can you provide the code that actually makes the call to this sub?

Comment: We are using a product named Boardwalk which is made on top of Excel. They have modified Excel by adding a lot of features and also their customized ribbon menu. We have done a lot of customization on this product to match our specific requirements. 
I asked them the question that from where are they calling Initialize method as I was not able to find, and they replied that they are using XML configuration to call it at the time of loading

Comment: Without knowing how you are calling the function and I don't know anything about Broadwalk, unfortunately there isn't much more I can offer. Hope you get this resolved

Answer (score 1):

Workbook functions don't have function `Initialize`. Refer [Workbook object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-object-excel)

Comment: I know that its not a workbook function...this is called at the time of loading by using XML configuration...so if I open the workbook it is configured that it calls this method(Initialize) after calling the workbook functions.